# Exception in Custom Action during RollBack

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-installer, custom-action

In custom action I override following function and got exception in rollback
case...

> "savedState dictionary does not
>   contain the expected values and might
>   have been corrupted. "

Is there any other way to rollback ?

```
   protected override void OnBeforeInstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {            
        try
        {                

            bool report = false; //Some validation
            if (!report)                
                throw new InstallException("License is not valid.");
            base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            base.Rollback(savedState);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change "base.Rollback()" in the exception handler to "throw;".  Your caller will call Rollback at the correct time.

Comment: For me throw is also not working. and It is giving the same error. please let me know what are the other options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pinvoke to call the cancel button on the base installer. This will rollback without any installexception error message dialogs.